# Trigger event listeners async with Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have created an abstract `Event` class which is used to create events in Kotlin. Now I would like to use Coroutines to call each subscriber asynchronously.

```
abstract class Event<T> {
    private var handlers = listOf<(T) -> Unit>()

    infix fun on(handler: (T) -> Unit) {
        handlers += handler
        println(handlers.count())
    }

    fun emit(event: T) =
        runBlocking {
            handlers.forEach { subscriber ->
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    subscriber(event)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And a concrete class that can be used to create event listeners and event publishers

```
class AsyncEventTest {
    companion object : Event<AsyncEventTest>()

    fun emit() = emit(this)
}
```

The issue is that when I run the following code I can see it creates all the listeners, but not even half of them are executed.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val random = Random(1000)

    runBlocking {
        // Create a 1000 event listeners with a random delay of 0 - 1000 ms
        for (i in 1..1000)
            AsyncEventTest on {
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    delay(random.nextLong())
                    println(i)
                }
            }
    }

    println("================")

    runBlocking {
        // Trigger the event
        AsyncEventTest().emit()
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

## Update

When I remove `delay(random.nextLong()`, all handlers are executed. This is weird, since I'm trying to simulate different response times from the handlers that way and I think a handler should always execute or throw an exception.

Comment: You should consider using coroutine channels instead of your custom approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the event listeners with `GlobalScope.launch()` that does not interact with the surrounding `runBlocking()` scope. Means `runBlocking()` returns  before all launched coroutines are finished. That is the reason you don't see the output.

BTW: your usage of coroutines and `runBlocking` is not recommended

You should add  `suspend` to the `emit()` function. The same is true for the `handler` parameter - make it suspendable.